# Why do some DATABASE_ROLE_MEMBER_CHANGE_GROUP audit events trigger but others don't?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

This statement triggers and audit event

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_data', N'BRANCH\NY-Users'
```

But this statement doesn't trigger any audit events

```
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BRANCH\MY_APP_User', @rolename = N'securityadmin'
```

I asked the DBA to create these audits in the Database.

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE SERVER AUDIT IT_Security_server_audit
TO APPLICATION_LOG
WITH
( QUEUE_DELAY = 1000
,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE
)
GO
 Alter Server Audit IT_Security_server_audit with(State=ON)
GO
CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION IT_Security_Server_Audit_Specification
FOR SERVER AUDIT IT_Security_server_audit
     ADD ( SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN_GROUP )
    ,ADD ( AUDIT_CHANGE_GROUP )
    ,ADD ( BACKUP_RESTORE_GROUP )
    ,ADD ( DATABASE_CHANGE_GROUP )
    ,ADD ( DATABASE_OWNERSHIP_CHANGE_GROUP )
    ,ADD ( BROKER_LOGIN_GROUP)
    ,ADD ( DBCC_GROUP )
    ,ADD ( LOGIN_CHANGE_PASSWORD_GROUP )
    ,ADD ( APPLICATION_ROLE_CHANGE_PASSWORD_GROUP )
    ,ADD (SERVER_PRINCIPAL_CHANGE_GROUP)
    ,ADD (DATABASE_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP)
    ,ADD (DATABASE_ROLE_MEMBER_CHANGE_GROUP)
WITH ( STATE = ON);
GO
--Create the database Audit spec
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION  IT_Security_Database_Audit_Specification
FOR SERVER AUDIT IT_Security_server_audit
       ADD ( AUDIT_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( BACKUP_RESTORE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( DATABASE_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( DATABASE_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( DATABASE_OBJECT_OWNERSHIP_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( DATABASE_OBJECT_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( DATABASE_ROLE_MEMBER_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( DBCC_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( SCHEMA_OBJECT_OWNERSHIP_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( DATABASE_ROLE_MEMBER_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( SCHEMA_OBJECT_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP )
       -- 2012-newer allowed events
       ,ADD ( DATABASE_LOGOUT_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( FAILED_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( USER_DEFINED_AUDIT_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP )
      -- New GROUPS
       ,ADD ( DATABASE_OWNERSHIP_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( DATABASE_PERMISSION_CHANGE_GROUP )
       ,ADD ( LOGIN_CHANGE_PASSWORD_GROUP )

WITH ( STATE = ON);
go
```

What is the difference between "sp_addrolemember" and "sp_addsrvrolemember" from an audit event perspective? Does the audit I have above not cover both scenarios?

Comment: Why use `sp_addrolemember` at all? It's been deprecated for years, use the `ALTER (SERVER) ROLE` syntax. Also, you've tagged 2008(R2) which are both completely out of support now too.

Comment: I’m in security so I don’t have control over what the users do. I just need to ensure I capture both scenarios.We are still using 2008 2008(R2) unfortunately. We’ve got a mixed bag of companies we’ve acquired. My task is to audit them all somehow.

Comment: To answer the quesion, the difference is one does database roles, the other server roles. They have been replaced by `ALTER ROLE` and `ALTER SERVER ROLE` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! I'm missing SERVER_ROLE_MEMBER_CHANGE_GROUP.

```
ALTER SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION  IT_Security_Server_Audit_Specification  
FOR SERVER AUDIT IT_Security_server_audit
        ADD (SERVER_ROLE_MEMBER_CHANGE_GROUP);  
GO
```